# In "盛りなる御代", how do you read "盛"

Tags: onyomi

"盛りなる御代..."
It's from Genjimonogatari.

My two cadidates are either もる ·さかる, so "mori-naru" ro "sakari-naru".

I can tell the meaning of the word, but I'm not sure which way I should read in this context, and in this specific book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[さかる](http://jisho.org/search/%E7%9B%9B%20%E3%81%95%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8B) is translated by jisho.org as `to prosper; to flourish,`  and [もる](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%9B%9B%E3%82%8B-1) is `to serve/to pile up.`

The definition you want there is definitely `to prosper; to flourish` since 御代 is [defined](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%BE%A1%E4%B8%96) as an `imperial reign.`

Putting it together,  盛り{さかり｝なる御代｛みよ｝ is a prosperous imperial reign.

Comment: Thank you. The online dictionary I used only showed the meanings and the readings all in one place without distinguishing the differences. I think I will try jisho.org. Perhaps this one will help me better.

Comment: If you're looking for kanji readings,  Make sure you type the character and then #KANJI right next to it when you search on jisho.org.  It's a fantastic resource.